# how to format the date from trello report?

Tags: trello, trello-organization

the format is this 1984-03-03T00:00:00.000Z  but require month, date, and year because i want to create a pivot report in google sheets for a monthly report.

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

#### ISO-8601 Date Format

Your values are in [ISO-8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html) format.  The simplest way to convert them is to use the [DATEVALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039) function.

#### DATEVALUE Function

[DATEVALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039) converts a provided date string in a known format to a date value.
**Syntax:** `DATEVALUE(date_string)`

###### Basic Formula

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10))

# Time would be similar
=TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,12,11))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

You would paste the formula down the column or alternatively use the [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) function.

#### BYROW Function

[BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) groups an array by rows by application of a [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) function to each row.
**Syntax:** `BYROW(array_or_range,LAMBDA)`

###### BYROW Formula

```
=BYROW(A:A, LAMBDA(r, 
   IF(r<>"", 
     DATEVALUE(LEFT(r,10)),
     IFERROR(1/0))))
```

[image]